# General Solution of Functional Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations

What is the general solution to:

$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \frac{1}{x} \tag{1}
$$

Obviously the solution to this for the limiting case of $h\to 0$ is 
$f(x) = \ln(x) + c$

Attempting to solve the case of $h=1$ poses some difficulties.

But I imagine that once I can cover the case of $h=1$ the rest shall become simpler

A related problem is that the solution to:

$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f(x) \tag{2}
$$

Can be assumed to have exponential form. Yielding:

$$a^{x+h} - a^{x} = ha^x \rightarrow a^h = 1+h \rightarrow a=(1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}}$$

Thus the general solution to this similar problem is:

$$f = (1+h)^{\frac{x}{h}}$$

Comment: Use another character instead of $\large{\rm e}$. People will be confused.

Comment: I looked up a few of the solutions and they all seem to be related to the digamma function (in fact, for $h=1$ that's just the recurrence relation for the digamma function).

Comment: @Silynn Where did you look?

Comment: WolframAlpha was able to compute a few solutions, and except for $h=1$ they were quite ugly.

Comment: I don't really mind ugly. What is the general form?

Comment: I am not sure why is this tagged ([tag:functional-analysis]).

Comment: @Martin Sleziak, I was hoping there was some way to resolve this using techniques such as infinite dimensional matrices etc...

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Sounds bombastic, but you probably mean expanding $f$ to some suitable (infinite) set of base functions and applying the functional equation to determine the coefficients.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I would not bet that your second functional equation leads to an exponential solution in that form. Usually you add a $\lim_{h->0}$ to the left hand side, which turns it into the differential equation $f' = f$, which has the solution $f(x) = f(0) \, e^x$.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Your second last equation is wrong. The functional equation for exponential functions is $f(x+y) = f(x)\, f(y)$, so $a^{x+h} - a^x = (a^h - 1) \, a^x = (\ln(a) \, h + O(h^2)) \, a^x = \ldots$

Comment: For $h=1$, you get $f(n)=C+\sum^n(1/k)$, and there's not much you can do to simplify that. The digamma is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the general solution for $f(x+1)-f(x)=1/x$ (assuming $f(x)$ is required to be defined for $x>0$) is as follows. $f(x)=f_0(x)$ can be an arbitrary function for $x\in(0,1]$ and then, for noninteger $x$, 
$$ 
 f(x) =f_0(x-[x])+\sum_{n=1}^{[x]}\frac 1{x-n},
$$
where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$, while 
$$
f(n)=f_0(1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k,\qquad n=2,3,\dots\,.
$$

In particular, the "general solution" in the OP is not general but only special.

Comment: How did you arrive at those results?

Comment: Rewrite the equation in the form $f(x+1)=f(x)+1/x$ and use induction on $[x]$. E.g. if $x\in(2,3]$, then $f(x)=f(x-1)+(x-1)^{-1}=f(x-2)+(x-2)^{-1}+(x-1)^{-1}=f_0(x-2)+(x-2)^{-1}+(x-1)^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you for that information!